# How to reduce the size of an application built with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I created an empty application on **Jetpack Compose**, enabled the **minifyEnabled = true** flag in it and compiled the release apk. Its size turned out to be **1.7 mb**, which, in my opinion, is a lot for an empty application.

Can I somehow reduce the size of the application?

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0-alpha10'
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.0-alpha06'
```

Comment: Proguard the things you don't use/want (which is horrible, time consuming, prone to error, and the way to do it). Also 1.7 Mb is not "too much" for an empty application. It's not empty, it has all those classes ready to be used (the material widgets, the lifecycle runtime and classes, the Android base runtime stuff, etc."

Answer (score 4):

As highlighted in https://twitter.com/vinaygaba/status/1488561816179331074, Compose apps should use:

```
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:{{ composeVersion }}"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:{{ composeVersion }}"
```

Instead of:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:{{ composeVersion }}"
```

By doing so, you are going to save a few hundred kbs from your app size.